# How to collect pairs of data based on timestamp

Tags: sql

I have this table:

[image]

What query should I write in order to get all the pairs of inputs that happen in a timeframe of up to 1 minute.

The end results that I need to receive from the above table should be:

[image]

Comment: you've tagged this question with mysql & BigQuery - which is it?

Comment: It is always good to provide the DDL to create the table and provide insert statements for populating the data in tables.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @GrahamPolley - BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

I did it in t-sql but I think its not so hard to translate in mysql.
Assuming that timestamp column is of datetime type then this query does what you are asking for (I tested it in t-sql so I created a table variable you have to use your table):

```
declare @table table (userid int, input varchar(50),timestmp datetime)
insert into @table values(1,'hy','1/19/2017 12:00')
insert into @table values(2,'by','1/19/2017 12:00')
insert into @table values(1,'hy2','1/19/2017 12:01')
insert into @table values(2,'by2','1/19/2017 12:01')
insert into @table values(3,'why','1/19/2017 12:01')
select t1.userid,t1.input,t2.input from @table t1 inner join @table t2 on t1.userid=t2.userid and t1.timestmp=DATEADD(mi,-1,t2.timestmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, it is giving expected output.

```
SELECT t1.userid,t1.input,t2.input 
      FROM test_table t1 
      INNER JOIN test_table t2 
         ON TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t1.timestmp,t2.timestmp) <= 1
            AND t1.userid = t2.userid
```

Note : Replace your table_name with `test_table`

Ask in case of any doubt.

Comment: same as answer above

Comment: aren't t-sql query and mysql query 2 different things?